# SP13: Calendar Conflict Check

Tags: 2013, workflow, calendar, sharepoint-calendar, script

I am working in SharePoint 2013 and seeking a way to add a calendar conflict check therefore end-users can not enter events into the calendar that will overlap with another event.

For instance, if there's a 3 meeting rooms. Person A adds an entry for Room #1 at 8AM-12PM on 6/5/2014. If Person B adds an entry for Room#1 for 11AM-1PM the conflict checker should not allow for this entry to be entered.  I know in SharePoint 2013 when you create a calendar "Check Double Booking" appears as a column type.  However, I am not sure if this is the same.

Do you know how I would go about adding a conflict checker to a calendar?  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

you can setup workflow which run every time new item calender is saved. Or you can perform list item event receiver to check with code than each time an item is saved.

Useful links:
https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/SharePoint-Double-Booking-with-the-Calendar.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue in my work place. I tried to setup workflow to prevent conflict, but it actually deleted some of the booking's end time.

So, now i have come up with an idea to solve this issue.I merged the sharepoint calendar into the outlook calendar. Now any user can easily add/edit booking without any conflict by looking into the outlook interface.

The only problem using outlook to manage sharepoint calendar is that, when anyone tried to edit the recurring booking it actually stop working from the outlook.

apart from that using outlook is effective way from my point of view.